# How do not use proxy with RestSharp in .NET Core 3

Tags: .net-core, httpclient, restsharp

I need to use RestSharp post without any default/system proxy. 
I did that with HttpClient with that :

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseProxy = false };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

How can I do something like that (UseProxy) with RestSharp?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this. note - `WebProxy` method is from `System.Net.WebProxy`

```
var proxy = new WebProxy("non_Existing_Server", 8888) {BypassProxyOnLocal = false};
var Client = new RestClient("http://www.google.com");
Client.Proxy = proxy;
```